# parts of rendering disappearing when moving focus (open3d)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, open3d

I have an issue with simple open3d rendering where, when panning (or zooming for that matter) the camera slightly in the viewer, only parts of the meshgrid are rendered (similar with pointclouds).

This picture is rendered correctly.
[image: rendered correctly]

I pan the image slightly using the mouse, probably around one or two degrees and get the following image.
[image: rendered incorrectly]

This panning or zooming further in any direction it sometimes get's better and sometimes worse. It seems to be consistent for a specific zoom/position/focus from what I can tell.
Could this have to do anything to do with opengl? Can I enable any options in open3d? Does it have to with my video card driver?

System:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 focal
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.13.0-39-generic
Uptime: 10d 6h 25m
Packages: 4548
Shell: zsh 5.8
Resolution: 2560x1440
WM: i3
Disk: 330G / 490G (71%)
CPU: Intel Core i7-8565U @ 8x 4.6GHz [63.0°C]
GPU: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake) (rev 02)
RAM: 22261MiB / 39904MiB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to coordinates not being represented by float32 precisely enough. Apparently, at some point, open3d uses float32 instead of float64, which results these weird visualization (and other) issues. Translating the points closer to 0,0,0 resolved the issue.

Also, see this: https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/discussions/4997